# Upload File and send the data via ajax

Tags: html, ajax, forms

Is there a way to use a php form. Have an upload type. Then When the user clicks a button, take the wanted "uploaded file" and send it via ajax?

How does one send data via ajax from a file?

Answer (score 0):

Useful link: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/